# Recover from skill -STOP -u root

Tags: linux

I was trying to logout previous logged-in root sessions, and stupidly, I typed
skill -STOP -u root

Now, I can't ssh back into the server. How do I recover?

Comment: Call the datacenter support, probably?

Comment: If there is no non-root process from which you can `su` then the sure way would be to reboot the machine.

Comment: I suggest you reboot and watch console. I've often configured servers with a serial connection and a non-root login that I know i can su from. I also give root login permissions to /dev/ttyS1, in case something removed the alternate account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a physical box then you'll need some form of lights-out or a nice person to bounce it face-to-face.

If it's virtual then you or someone else needs to deal with it via whatever management console you or they have.

Answer (score 0):

If you were lucky enough to already be logged in (not as root), you could `sudo` or `su` and make it right.  Otherwise, you are S.O.L. without a reset switch.